# doubts of Python's collection.defaultdict usage

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-collections

I understand collections.defaultdict is assigning default value to a dict like this:

```
dict = collections.defaultdict(int) # default value of dict is 0
```

or

```
dict = collections.defaultdict(lambda: 5) # default value of dict is 5
```

Then I see a usage of defaultdict in Python like this:

```
_dict = lambda : collections.defaultdict(_dict)
dict = _dict()

dict = dict["A"]
dict = dict["B"]
dict = dict["C"]
```

I am very confused of the first line:

```
_dict = lambda: collections.defaultdict(_dict)
```

What is exactly the default value? It seems it is an endless recursion.

Comment: Perhaps you forgot a `lambda` somewhere? See [How to convert defaultdict of defaultdicts \[of defaultdicts\] to dict of dicts \[of dicts\]?](//stackoverflow.com/q/26496831) for example, which uses a 'recursive' definition. The trick there is that `factory` is not looked up until you *call* `factory`, at which point the name exists..

Comment: @MartijnPieters forgot to add lambda ahead. See my updates

Comment: Yes, it's recursive, but it's not endless. As Martijn said "The trick there is that `factory` is not looked up until you call `factory`".

Comment: All the lambda does is define a defaultdict that reuses the same factory. That just makes nested values a new defaultdict with the factory shared. That's not *endless*. It's called *auto-vivication*.

Answer (score 0):

`defaultdict()` takes a *factory*, and will *call* the factory each time it needs a default value. If you pass in `int`, every time a new default value is needed, `int()` is called.

The code you found use a `lambda` as the factory. Every time you call it, it returns a new `defaultdict(...)` object. Now, the `defaultdict()` object still needs a factory, and in this case, it just *reuses the same factory object*.

This works, because the name `_dict` is only looked up when call the lambda, and you can only call the lambda once it is created and assigned to the name `_dict`; the dependency cycle works because the self-reference is only looked up after the reference has been created.

This is a lot like recursion, but not the same thing. Recursion *automatically* calls the same function until an end-condition breaks the call chain. But here, there is no automatic call chain! When you need a new default value, the `lambda` is called, and that returns a new `defaultdict(_dict)` object. *And that's it*. There is no automatic chain, the newly-minted `defaultdict` has a factory of it's own configured, but it is not automatically called.

The concept is called [autovivication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autovivification).

Comment: when you say "the newly-minted defaultdict has a factory of it's own configured", does it mean it will return dict "{}"? Where is the default value "{}" returned exactly?

Comment: @derek: no, it won't return `{}`. It's another `defaultdict` object, and if you try to access a non-existing key, it'll call the factory to produce a value.

Comment: @derek: that factory then creates another `defaultdict` object, which has a factory configured. Etc.